# Looking for advice on best practice for storing user preferences

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core, cloud, blazor

I am building a dotnet core, blazor server web app that is to be hosted in Azure, and I am looking for some suggestions/best practice advice on what would be the best solution to allow me to store user specific application configuration. For example, dark mode enabled, search preferences etc.

I am currently thinking of using something like SQL to persist the data that I could then cache in memory, (however, this might not work well in a scale out senario in the cloud), or using Redis cache maybe.

I wanted to get a steer from the community as to whether there are any other solutions/practices that I could explore that I have not considered.

I really do appreciate any advice of help you can offer, any web research I have done has seamed to point me down the road of how to save application settings such as connection strings etc which is not quite what I am after.

Comment: There are lots of things to consider here. Is the user going to be using the same device every time? Are their preferences different per device (screen size etc). Security implications of settings stored in a browser storage need to be considered as well.

Comment: Local storage could be an option as Brian said depending on requirements: https://github.com/Blazored/LocalStorage

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to store the user preferences provided by the browser.

- Local storage
- IndexedDB database
- Cookies
- File and Directory Entries API

Refer here to  [implement the best practices.](https://www.meziantou.net/storing-user-settings-in-a-blazor-webassembly-application.htm)

Please have a look for storing user preferences [asp net core blazor web api how to securely store user data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67591664/asp-net-core-blazor-web-api-how-to-securely-store-user-data)